# How can Iterate and determine whether an array is empty in a tab control?

Tags: c#, arrays, tabcontrol

I'm sorry that the title is confusing but I did not know how to ask this question; if someone can help with a better title I would appreciate it.

I am building a database of players and their match performance. The matches are displayed using a tab control, inside the matches are fields that are stored in a panel. The amount of matches goes up to 5, therefore each field is an array of size 5 to represent different values for different matches. I have ran into the problem of trying to save the amount of tabs (matches) there are for that unique player.

Because the amount of tabs carries over to the next player shown, I tried to iterate through all the matches and all the fields for that player, determine which matches contain empty fields and respectively delete that tab (match). So if player 1 has 3 matches with values in fields, but player 2 only has 2 matches that contain values in fields, the 3rd match (tab) will be deleted as the fields have no values.

to better explain, this is the GUI:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNOiP.png)

My attempt at iterating through the field of each match looks like this:

```
int[] csNumberTF = ((Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown]).csNumber[tabMatches.SelectedIndex];
int i = 0;
        while (i < 5)
        {
            if (csNumberTF[i] == 0)
            {
                int tabsLeft = tabMatches.TabCount;
                if(tabsLeft > 1)
                tabMatches.TabPages.Remove(tabMatches.SelectedTab);
                tabsLeft--;
            }
            i++;
        }
```

However I am presented with the error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'int[]'`

I would really appriciate if someone could help me out here,  I understand that the code is long but It is organised and titled so that should help.

Full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace Assignment1_Template2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    // =======================DATA STRUCTURE ===========================
    [Serializable]

    private struct Player
    {   //CONSTRUCTOR
        public Player(int noOfMatches)
        {
            uniquePlayerId = new int[noOfMatches];

            playerIgName = "";
            contactStreet = "";
            contactTown = "";
            contactPostcode = "";
            contactEmail = "";
            contactTelephone = "";
            imagePath = "";
            matchesCount = 0;
            csNumber = new int[noOfMatches];
            killsNumber = new int[noOfMatches];
            deathsNumber = new int[noOfMatches];
            assistsNumber = new int[noOfMatches];
            minutesNumber = new int[noOfMatches];
            for (int i = 0; i < noOfMatches; ++i)
            {
                uniquePlayerId[i] = 0;
                csNumber[i] = 0;
                killsNumber[i] = 0;
                deathsNumber[i] = 0;
                assistsNumber[i] = 0;
                minutesNumber[i] = 0;
            }
        }

        //DATA TYPES
        public int[] uniquePlayerId;
        public int[] csNumber;
        public int[] killsNumber;
        public int[] deathsNumber;
        public int[] assistsNumber;
        public int[] minutesNumber;
        public int matchesCount;
        public string playerIgName;
        public string contactStreet;
        public string contactTown;
        public string contactPostcode;
        public string contactEmail;
        public string contactTelephone;
        public string imagePath;
    }

    //GLOBAL VARIABLES
    public ArrayList GameDB;
    public ArrayList playerMatch;
    private int currentEntryShown = 0;
    private int numberOfEntries = 0;
    private string filename = "W:\\test.dat"; 
    public string prevImage = "";

    // =========================================================================
    // ====================== STARTING POINT ===================================
    // =========================================================================
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GameDB = new ArrayList();
        LoadData();
        ShowData();
        UpdatePrevNextBtnStatus();
    }

    // =========================================================================
    // ========================= BUTTON ACTION HANDLERS ========================
    // =========================================================================
    private void showPreviousBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        --currentEntryShown;
        ShowData();
        UpdatePrevNextBtnStatus();
    }

    private void showNextBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ++currentEntryShown;
        if (currentEntryShown < GameDB.Count)
        {
            ShowData();
        }
        UpdatePrevNextBtnStatus();
    }

    private void addNewPlayerBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ++numberOfEntries;
        currentEntryShown = numberOfEntries - 1;
        Player aNewStruct = new Player(5);
        GameDB.Add(aNewStruct);
        ShowData();
        addNewPlayerBtn.Enabled = true;
        UpdatePrevNextBtnStatus();
    }
    private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveData();
        addNewPlayerBtn.Enabled = true;
        UpdatePrevNextBtnStatus();
    }
    private void deletePlayerBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        numberOfEntries--;
        GameDB.RemoveAt(currentEntryShown);
        SaveData();
        currentEntryShown--;
        if (currentEntryShown <= GameDB.Count)
        {
            ShowData();
        }

        UpdatePrevNextBtnStatus();
    }
    private void uploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Select an image file";
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Player aNewStruct = new Player(5);
                aNewStruct = (Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown];
                aNewStruct.imagePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                GameDB[currentEntryShown] = aNewStruct;
                playerPictureBox.ImageLocation = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    private void searchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string toFind;
        string source;

        toFind = searchInput.Text;
        toFind = toFind.ToLower();

        for (int i = 0; i < GameDB.Count; ++i)
        {   
            source = ((Player)GameDB[i]).playerIgName + ((Player)GameDB[i]).contactStreet;
            source = source.ToLower(); 

            if (source.Contains(toFind))
            {
                currentEntryShown = i;
                ShowData();
                UpdatePrevNextBtnStatus();
                break; 
            }

            if (i == (GameDB.Count - 1))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(toFind + " not found");
            }

        }
    }
    private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveData();
        UpdatePrevNextBtnStatus();

    }
    private void addNewMatchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage newTP = new TabPage();
        if (tabMatches.TabCount <= 4)
        {
            tabMatches.TabPages.Add(newTP);
            int TabPageNumber = tabMatches.SelectedIndex + 1;
            tabMatches.TabPages[TabPageNumber].Text = "Match " + (TabPageNumber + 1);

            tabMatches.SelectTab(TabPageNumber);
            deleteMatchBtn.Enabled = true;

            panel1.Parent = tabMatches.SelectedTab;
        }

        ShowData();
    }
    private void deleteMatchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabMatches.TabPages.Remove(tabMatches.SelectedTab);
        int lastTabNumber = tabMatches.TabCount - 1;
        tabMatches.SelectTab(lastTabNumber);
        if (tabMatches.SelectedIndex < 1) deleteMatchBtn.Enabled = false;
    }

    // =========================================================================
    // ================ HANDLE DATA CHANGES BY USER ============================
    // =========================================================================
    private void playerIdBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Player aNewStruct = new Player(5);
        aNewStruct = (Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown];
        aNewStruct.uniquePlayerId[0] = Convert.ToInt32(playerIdBox.Text);
        GameDB[currentEntryShown] = aNewStruct;
    }
    private void playerIgNameBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Player aNewStruct = new Player(5);
        aNewStruct = (Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown];
        aNewStruct.playerIgName = playerIgNameBox.Text;
        GameDB[currentEntryShown] = aNewStruct;
    }
    private void contactStreetBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Player aNewStruct = new Player(5);
        aNewStruct = (Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown];
        aNewStruct.contactStreet = contactStreetBox.Text;
        GameDB[currentEntryShown] = aNewStruct;
    }

    private void contactTownBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Player aNewStruct = new Player(5);
        aNewStruct = (Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown];
        aNewStruct.contactTown = contactTownBox.Text;
        GameDB[currentEntryShown] = aNewStruct;
    }

    private void contactPostcodeBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Player aNewStruct = new Player(5);
        aNewStruct = (Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown];
        aNewStruct.contactPostcode = contactPostcodeBox.Text;
        GameDB[currentEntryShown] = aNewStruct;
    }

    private void contactEmailBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Player aNewStruct = new Player(5);
        aNewStruct = (Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown];
        aNewStruct.contactEmail = contactEmailBox.Text;
        GameDB[currentEntryShown] = aNewStruct;
    }

    private void contactTelephoneBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Player aNewStruct = new Player(5);
        aNewStruct = (Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown];
        aNewStruct.contactTelephone = contactTelephoneBox.Text;
        GameDB[currentEntryShown] = aNewStruct;
    }

    //Match data
    private void tabMatches_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        panel1.Parent = tabMatches.SelectedTab;
        ShowData();

    }

    private void numCS_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Player aNewStruct = new Player(5);
        aNewStruct = (Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown];
        aNewStruct.csNumber[tabMatches.SelectedIndex] = (int)numCS.Value;
        GameDB[currentEntryShown] = aNewStruct;
    }

    private void numKills_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Player aNewStruct = new Player(5);
        aNewStruct = (Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown];
        aNewStruct.killsNumber[tabMatches.SelectedIndex] = (int)numKills.Value;
        GameDB[currentEntryShown] = aNewStruct;
    }

    private void numDeaths_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Player aNewStruct = new Player(5);
        aNewStruct = (Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown];
        aNewStruct.deathsNumber[tabMatches.SelectedIndex] = (int)numDeaths.Value;
        GameDB[currentEntryShown] = aNewStruct;
    }

    private void numAssists_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Player aNewStruct = new Player(5);
        aNewStruct = (Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown];
        aNewStruct.assistsNumber[tabMatches.SelectedIndex] = (int)numAssists.Value;
        GameDB[currentEntryShown] = aNewStruct;
    }

    private void numMinutes_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Player aNewStruct = new Player(5);
        aNewStruct = (Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown];
        aNewStruct.minutesNumber[tabMatches.SelectedIndex] = (int)numMinutes.Value;
        GameDB[currentEntryShown] = aNewStruct;
    }

    // =========================================================================
    // ================= HELPER METHODS FOR DISPLAYING DATA ====================
    // =========================================================================
    private void ShowData()
    {
        playerIdBox.Text = ((Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown]).uniquePlayerId[0].ToString();
        playerIgNameBox.Text = ((Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown]).playerIgName;
        contactStreetBox.Text = "" + ((Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown]).contactStreet;
        contactTownBox.Text = "" + ((Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown]).contactTown;
        contactPostcodeBox.Text = "" + ((Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown]).contactPostcode;
        contactEmailBox.Text = "" + ((Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown]).contactEmail;
        contactTelephoneBox.Text = "" + ((Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown]).contactTelephone;
        playerPictureBox.ImageLocation = ((Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown]).imagePath;

        numCS.Value = ((Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown]).csNumber[tabMatches.SelectedIndex];
        numKills.Value = ((Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown]).killsNumber[tabMatches.SelectedIndex];
        numDeaths.Value = ((Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown]).deathsNumber[tabMatches.SelectedIndex];
        numAssists.Value = ((Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown]).assistsNumber[tabMatches.SelectedIndex];
        numMinutes.Value = ((Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown]).killsNumber[tabMatches.SelectedIndex];

        int[] csNumberTF = ((Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown]).csNumber[tabMatches.SelectedIndex];
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 5)
        {
            if (csNumberTF[i] == 0)
            {
                int tabsLeft = tabMatches.TabCount;
                if(tabsLeft > 1)
                {
                    tabMatches.TabPages.Remove(tabMatches.SelectedTab);
                    tabsLeft--;
                }

            }
            i++;
        }            

    }
    private void UpdatePrevNextBtnStatus()
    {
        if (currentEntryShown > 0) showPreviousBtn.Enabled = true;
        else showPreviousBtn.Enabled = false;

        if (currentEntryShown < (numberOfEntries - 1)) showNextBtn.Enabled = true;
        else showNextBtn.Enabled = false;

        label1.Text = "Player ID";
        label3.Text = (currentEntryShown + 1) + " / " + numberOfEntries;
    }

    // =========================================================================
    // =============== HELPER METHODS FOR LOADING AND SAVING ===================
    // =========================================================================
    private void SaveData()
    {
        try
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            try
            {
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                bf.Serialize(fs, GameDB);
                MessageBox.Show("Data saved to " + filename, "FILE SAVE OK", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Could not serialise to " + filename,
                                 "FILE SAVING PROBLEM", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            fs.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not open " + filename +
                            " for saving.\nNo access rights to the folder, perhaps?",
                             "FILE SAVING PROBLEM", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
    }
    private void LoadData()
    {

        try
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            try
            {
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                GameDB = (ArrayList)bf.Deserialize(fs);

                currentEntryShown = 0;
                numberOfEntries = GameDB.Count;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Could not de-serialise from " + filename +
                                "\nThis usually happens after you changed the data structure.\nDelete the data file and re-start program\n\nClick 'OK' to close the program",
                                "FILE LOADING PROBLEM", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                fs.Close();             
                Environment.Exit(1);    
            }
            fs.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Could not open " + filename + " for loading.\nFile might not exist yet.\n(This would be normal at first start)\n\nCreate a default data file?",
                                "FILE LOADING PROBLEM", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Player aNewStruct = new Player(5);
                GameDB.Add(aNewStruct);
                numberOfEntries = 1;
                currentEntryShown = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    // =========================================================================
    // ====================== HELPER METHODS FOR SORTING =======================
    // =========================================================================
    private void sortToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GameDB.Sort(new PlayerNameComparer());
        currentEntryShown = 0;
        ShowData();
        UpdatePrevNextBtnStatus();
    }
    public class PlayerNameComparer : IComparer
    {
        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            return ((Player)x).playerIgName.CompareTo(((Player)y).playerIgName);
        }
    }

    // =========================================================================
    // ====================== MISC STUFF =======================================
    // =========================================================================
    private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void developerToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("By Szymon Zmudzki: 13042432");
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change this

```
int[] csNumberTF = ((Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown]).csNumber[tabMatches.SelectedIndex];
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 5)
        {
            if (csNumberTF[i] == 0)
            {
                int tabsLeft = tabMatches.TabCount;
                if(tabsLeft > 1)
                {
                    tabMatches.TabPages.Remove(tabMatches.SelectedTab);
                    tabsLeft--;
                }

            }
            i++;
        }
```

To use the csNumber which is int[] in the for loop

```
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 5)
        {
            if (((Player)GameDB[currentEntryShown]).csNumber[i] == 0)
            {
                int tabsLeft = tabMatches.TabCount;
                if(tabsLeft > 1)
                {
                    tabMatches.TabPages.Remove(tabMatches.SelectedTab);
                    tabsLeft--;
                }

            }
            i++;
        }
```

To find out the value of tabMatches.TabCount, add this line when you run the program and see it in the output window: (To answer your question, I would assume the TabCount start with 1. That's the default value of any .Count() call to an array of integer. But this is the best way to know for sure.)

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(tabMatches.TabCount);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works and answers my question. Also do you know if .TabCount starts at 0 or 1?

Comment: Try to print it out and take a look at when you run the program. I'll edit the answer to show you. :)